# Iteration algorithm in R for least squares estimation of high dimensional regressions

Tags: r, iteration, regression, linear-regression, least-squares

I have a matched employer-employee data set with 20 years of information on around 2.000.000 individuals and 400.000 firms. Amongst several worker- and firm-level covariates, I have worker, firm and occupation identifiers. My objective is to obtain 3 vectors of worker, firm and occupation fixed effects, estimated through a wage equation. I want to implement the Gauss-Seidel algorithm to obtain the exact least squares solution.

In a nutshell, I need to start with the three fixed effects' variables equal to zero, followed by estimation of the wage equation and update of each of the three coefficients sequentially until convergence is met, based on some convergence criterion (in this case, I'm following [Guimaraes & Portugal 2010](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1101000406) by using a comparison between the residual sum of squares). I tried to do it in stata but it was taking too long to converge, so I'm now trying to do it in R.

My R code:

```
estimate_fixed_effects = function(df, max_iter = 1000, tol = 1e-6) {
     y = df$real_lrganho
     X = model.matrix(~ p_age2 + antig + antig2 + firm_age + lfprod, df)
     beta = rep(0, ncol(X))
     worker_fe = rep(0, length(unique(df$ntrab)))
     firm_fe = rep(0,length(unique(df$emp_id)))
     occupation_fe = rep(0,length(unique(df$occupation4)))
     for (iter in 1:max_iter){
         for (i in 1:length(worker_fe)) {
             y_i = y[df$ntrab == i]
             X_i = X[df$ntrab == i,]
             beta = lm(y_i - X_i %*% beta ~ 0)$coefficients
             worker_fe[i] = mean(y_i - X_i %*% beta)
             }
         for (j in 1:length(firm_fe)) {
             y_j = y[df$emp_id == j]
             X_j = X[df$emp_id == j,]
             beta = lm(y_j - X_j %*% beta ~ 0)$coefficients
             firm_fe[j] = mean(y_j - X_j %*% beta)
             }
         for (k in 1:length(occupation_fe)) {
             y_k = y[df$occupation4 == k]
             X_k = X[df$occupation4 == k,]
             beta = lm(y_k - X_k %*% beta ~ 0)$coefficients
             occupation_fe[k] = mean(y_k - X_k %*% beta)
             }
         beta_new = lm(y - rowSums(model.matrix(~ ntrab + emp_id + occupation4, df) %*% c(worker_fe, firm_fe, occupation_fe)) ~ X - 1)$coefficients
         if (max(abs(beta_new - beta))<tol) {
             break
             }
         beta = beta_new
         }
     return(list(beta = beta, worker_fe = worker_fe, firm_fe = firm_fe, occupation_fe = occupation_fe))
     }
```

The output should ideally be 3 vectors of estimated fixed effects for the 3 identified groups. However, after running `result = estimate_fixed_effects(df)`, I got the error message "Error in X[df$ntrab == i, ] : (subscript) logical subscript too long". When trying to make sense of this output, I realize that I'm not entirely sure of how `model.matrix()` even works, and how to make the function do what I want. Any ideas?

Edit: I fixed the first error message, it had to do with a mismatch between the model matrix and `df$ntrab`, because of missing values on `lfprod`. Now I'm facing the following error which I don't understand: `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': non-conformable arguments`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest starting with a simpler example. Instead of fixed effects for 3 separate variables, maybe start with 1. Instead of 2M individual and 400k firms, start with a small, much more manageable example. When you have it working for a simple case, then scale it up.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you, I might just try and do that. That was my approach to make it run on stata, and I thought I would just go for the whole thing in R. I'm still thinking I'm missing something fundamental about what `model.matrix()` does, and that the error is associated to the dimension of the worker vector. So the solution on a simpler, smaller model might not scale to the whole sample... But I'll still do just that, thank you

Comment: I haven't looked at this in detail, but this approach (looping over workers, firms, and occupations explicitly) seems like it will be horribly slow.  Has someone not implemented something like this already, either with sparse linear algebra or with iterations implemented in a lower-level language?  Maybe the `lfe` package? Check the "panel models" section of https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.html ?

Comment: Yeah, as far as model matrix, I'd give the same advice. Try it out on small sample so you can see what it does. Or if you have a specific question about model matrix, please ask it.